# Problem running tor services

Tags: configuration, ubuntu

[image]New to creating Tor_Hidden_Services. I created a website on Mobirise software and i wanted to run the site in Tor_Hidden_Services. I started with a tutorial from a friend which with his instructions, i Downloaded Oracle VirtualBox, then installed Ubuntu 20.

After moving the website files through Google drive account (Chrome browser) on my windows 10, i signed into the account using firefox on the Ubuntu Os then downloaded the file.

We started running this command in the terminal:

- `sudo apt install nginx` - Downloaded Nginx
- `sudo nautilus` - With permission granted, i was able to move the website file to the destination shown on the picture.
- `sudo apt install tor` - Installed tor services
- I went to my browser and typed `http://localhost/` it displayed the website i wanted to run in tor.
- Now he told me to enter `sudo gedit /etc/tor/torrc` which showed the tor configurations in a text editor.
- In the text editior he told me to uncomment this here and there `#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/`,`#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80` and to look like this...

```
############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###
HiddenServicePort x y:z says to redirect requests on port x to the
 address y:z.
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

After that i saved the file.

***Having Problem Here***
 - Then told me to Open terminal and type `sudo tor` and this was the result:

```
May 08 02:32:21.960 [notice] Tor 0.3.0.8 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1f, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.4.4.
May 08 02:32:21.961 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 08 02:32:21.961 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 08 02:32:21.967 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ failed: Permission denied
May 08 02:32:21.967 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
May 08 02:32:21.967 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

*Please somebody help me out, i am stuck here and dont't know what next to do after, because the person helping me, has been off for days......*

- [![][2]][2]

Answer (score 1):

The important line is:

> ```
> May 08 02:32:21.967 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ failed: Permission denied
> ```

The Tor process checks the permissions of this directory and if they are wrong it fails. You can check them by opening  your terminal and entering the command:

```
sudo ls -la /var/lib/tor/
```

There should be a line which ends with `hidden_service`:

```
drwx--S---  2 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 May  5 12:53 hidden_service
```

The first part of the line shows the permissions: `drwx--S---`. They are different in your output. So to solve this, enter the following command:

```
sudo chmod 2700 /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
```

If you now enter `sudo ls -la /var/lib/tor/` you should see the same permissions as above.

Furthermore I'd recommend to check the owner of the directory. Like in the output above it should list `debian-tor` as owner. If this is not the case change it by entering:

```
sudo chown debian-tor:debian-tor /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
```

The last step is to restart your Tor process:

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

Now your hidden service should work. You can check the contents of `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname`. The file lists the onion name. Enter this in your browser and you should see your web site.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply But....

I did all of this things but the problem still persists. After getting my hostname, i searched it on Tor browser and it came out *"Unable to connect"* _"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at xabkqgkmc7mcl3o3zncmefo5yhlbuwvwhxkgfxirtsiuj67zour7ij32qd.onion"_.. I typed "tor" in the terminal and the problem still exists.

Comment: Did you try to follow the advice above? What is the output of the Tor rpocess when you start it?

Comment: Yes i followed the advice and this was the process:

`drago@drago-VirtualBox:~$ sudo systemctl restart tor
[sudo] password for drago: 
drago@drago-VirtualBox:~$` 

It didn't actually give any output.

Comment: Please describe step by step what you did.

Comment: I resolved the issue. But now another came up. When i typed my address in Tor browser and the result was "Server not found".. I checked my tor status with "sudo systemctl status tor@default" and output said "Active: Failed" with a red colour.