# Why always permission Denied

Tags: configuration

I don't know if asking this question here, is really right or if "Ask Ubuntu" section in stack would be in a better position to answer, but i gotta try, because it is still related to tor. So in my previous post, i was asking how to solve this 
`May 20 12:40:35.541 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1f, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.4.4.
May 20 12:40:35.541 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 20 12:40:35.541 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 20 12:40:35.547 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ cannot be read: Permission denied
May 20 12:40:35.547 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
May 20 12:40:35.547 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.` [Problem running tor services](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21230/problem-running-tor-services), Which someone posted an answer, but the answer didn't work.

**Question**

1. So i was thinking if it's possible to disable whatever that is asking for permissions, so that whatever i do in my terminal, i won't need to type in sudo or have some sort of permission denied when running some commands.
2. What really are those error output saying (That would help me understand what am doing wrong and right)

*Also i'll be glad if someone helps me with a solution to the "Problem running tor services"*

Comment: Do you plan on running your hidden service all the time? If so, you shouldn't be running tor manually. When you `apt install tor`, you had installed tor as a systemd service. You can check its status with `sudo systemctl status tor@default` and its log with `sudo journalctl -u tor@default`. Please also run `sudo ls -la /var/lib/tor` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I typed in **sudo ls -la /var/lib/tor** and this was the output: 
" .  cached-certs  cached-microdescs      hidden_service  lock
..  cached-microdesc-consensus cached-microdescs.new  keys        state''

Comment: The `-ls` option should provide much more information than that.

Comment: Sorry about that, i made a mistake this the output. 
**drwx--S---  4 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 May 21 20:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 68 root       root          4096 May 18 22:23 ..
-rw-------  1 debian-tor debian-tor   20442 May 18 22:23 cached-certs
-rw-------  1 debian-tor debian-tor 2071758 May 21 20:28 cached-microdesc-consensus
-rw-------  1 debian-tor debian-tor 5474139 May 18 22:38 cached-microdescs
-rw-------  1 debian-tor debian-tor 1176279 May 21 20:29 cached-microdescs.new**

Comment: **drwx--S---  3 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 May 21 10:37 hidden_service
drwx--S---  2 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 May 18 22:23 keys
-rw-------  1 debian-tor debian-tor       0 May 21 10:37 lock
-rw-------  1 debian-tor debian-tor   23176 May 21 20:29 state**

Comment: I resolved the issue.